# ubuntu14.04 opencv VideoCaption() missing picture in access unit

Tags: python, opencv

I got stucked when I tried to using cv2.VideoCapture() to read a video. It tells me that missing picture in access unit, how can I fixed it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xq6v4.png)

Comment: I found this problem is caused by ffmpeg is not installed correctly.